# Double Spinner for Android

Tags: android, user-interface, spinner, android-spinner

I'm new to this forum, but i came here because i need some help with some spinners i'm trying to create for an Android app.

I have created 1 spinner and that works fine, but now i want to add a second spinner and i want the if statement i have to work depending on the two selections of the spinners.

For example, if item 1 is selected on spinner 1 and item 3 is selected on spinner 2 then do the if statement.

But i don't know how to get that to work. could anyone help me please.

This is the code i have now for 1 spinner:

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.weight_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());



    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener
     {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) 
    {
        final String itemSelected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

        if (valueEntered.getText().length() == 0)
            {
                valueEntered.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            }

        if (itemSelected.equals("Stones"))
      {
            float valueInput = Float.parseFloat(valueEntered.getText().toString());
          Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The scale is " +
                  parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          valueEntered.setText(String.valueOf(convertSToK(valueInput)));

      }

    }
```

I really need some help, many thanks,

Davide Sousa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dialog like the spinner:

```
private Dialog b1()
{
    final String[] items = {
            "Item 1",
            "Item2",};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Hi this is a spinner"));
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            switch(item) {
            case 0:{
                /* Item 1 */ break;}
            case 1:{
                /* Item 2 */break;}
            }
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

and then show the dialog with `b1().show();`

Comment: im not quite sure what you mean, and how to get this to work.

Comment: Cant i just create 2 seperate spinners, and then make an if statement like if(spinner1.itemselected = "Stones" && spinner2.itemselected = "Kg")

Comment: this code show a dialog that looks same than the Spinner. just copy and paste the code and use b1().show(); in the part that you want to show the second spinner.  if this is not what you want then explain better the question and i will try help you

Comment: Yeah, works well. Many Thanks Mate. Enjoy the New Year 2012!! :D